# Why AVCaptureSession image is scaled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

I am using this standard example to show video from camera to iPhone screen. I can see video BUT it is zoomed. When I use standard iPhone camera app I can see more on picture.

I am pretty sure that answer is simple, but it seems my english is not good enough to make a right search phrase.

[image: my app screenshot]

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    cameraPreview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,720,1280)] ;
    [self.view addSubview:cameraPreview] ;

    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

    CALayer *viewLayer = cameraPreview.layer;
    NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = cameraPreview.bounds;
    [cameraPreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    [session startRunning];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AV Foundation camera preview layer gets zoomed in, how to zoom out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676607/av-foundation-camera-preview-layer-gets-zoomed-in-how-to-zoom-out)

Comment: I am an idiot.

cameraPreview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,720,1280)] ;

Screen is 320 x 568.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible reason, the first one is about the resolution of the frames that you are getting, `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`means different res on different devices. Once you get the frames they should be shown inside the preview layer.
The `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` has aspect mode like a `UIImageView` called `-videoGravity`.
Size of the frames combined to different videoGravity can change the way the preview layer shows them.

Comment: Hi @Andrea can you recommend how to capture full screen video on the 5S and other larger devices? Having difficulty ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704032/swift-video-records-at-one-size-but-renders-at-wrong-size/34710892. Thanks!